# SQL, getting the correct conversion rate based on the date

Tags: sql-server-2008, with-statement

Hello and thank you for your help I am creating a View in SQL 2008, I need to convert amounts into a different currency, I also need to make sure it is using the appropriate currency based on date. Before I went with just creating an average of the Month to simplify my conversion but I think having each field calculated individually is better.

The Data from my currency table looks like so(simplified) TABLE A.

```
HOMECUR  SOURCECUR RATEDATE  RATE 
USD      CAD       20120314  1.0086000
USD      CAD       20120316  1.0087000
```

The Data from the amount table looks like so(simplified) TABLE B.

```
RATEDATE TRANSAMT FISCALYR FISCALPERD ACCTID
20120314 120.00   2012     05         123456
```

So my question is, what can I put to have the RATE that matches the RATEDATE and if that does not exist the RATEDATE the next RATEDATE just before.

Overall, I am grouping data by acctID, FISCALYR and FISCALPERD and SUMing the conveted amounts, but I decided to convert the amounts before SUMing them with a WITH statement.

```
ALTER VIEW vJFTESTVIEW
AS
    WITH        
    ActualRateHAIUSA as(
        SELECT POP =  rat.RATE * act.TRANSAMT,
               act.FISCALYR,
               act.FISCALPERD,
               act.ACCTID as ACID
        FROM 
            TABLEA rat,
            TABLEB act
        WHERE -- as my table shows TABLE B's RATEDATE is on the 15th of March
              --, while TABLE A does not have the 15th of March. 
              --It should then take the one 14h instead 
              --(the next closest date while not going the original date) 
              AND rat.HOMECUR = 'CAD'
              AND rat.SOURCECUR = 'USD' 
    )
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: My apologies, I want to know how I can get the accurate RATE from TABLE A. The accurate rate is determined by TABLEB.RATEDATE = TABLEA.RATEDATE OR the RATEDATE just before it. (Updating my question)

Comment: You need to create ExchangeRate by Date Ranges & Then sum up the Transaction Amounts by the RateDate. This link should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306462/sql-join-against-date-ranges

Comment: Thanks Akhill, I looked at that link before posting this one and it was very confusing to me. I will look into it again and try to make it work for me.