# Extract only variables which is greater than other table in influxDB

Tags: sql

I am using influxDB and I would like to extract some values which is greater than certain threshold in other table.

For example, I have two tables as shown in below.

**Table A**

```
Time     value
1         15
2         25
3         9
4         22
```

**Table B**

```
Time     threshold
1         16
2         12
3         13
4         15
```

Give above two tables, I would like to extract three values which is greater than first row in `Table B`. Therefore what I want to have is as below.

```
   Time     value
    2         25
    4         22
```

I tried it using below sql query, but it didn't give any correct result.

`select * from data1 where value > (select spec from spec1 limit1);`

Look forward to your feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the condition in an inner join:

```
select * from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b on a.id=b.id and a.value > b.threshold
```

When your time column doesn't only include integer values, you have to format the time and join on a time range. Here is an example:
[SQL join on time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306462/sql-join-against-date-ranges)